# Regular expression to find " but not the ones that have ","

Tags: regex

I just cant get the hang of regular expressions, trying to find the " , but not the ones with , on either side

I ","can haz ","kittens. "Mmmm". Tasty, tasty kittens.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to specify a language tag. Your answer depends on whether your language supports look-ahead/behind or not.

Comment: Why, what's the purpose - there may be an alternative, way or it might alter the final expression (language comes into play here as well)

Comment: Not sure what language, I'd just like to do a search/replace in Notepad++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
    (?<!,)"(?!,)
```

Or, allowing for whitespace:

```
    (?<!,\s*)"(?!\s*,)
```

Comment: As Sahand Mozaffari notes, the language you're using must support lookbehind/lookahead assertions.  If it does not, then you might try ``[^,]"[^,]`` but this will fail you if two quotes appear together, e.g. ``""``, and also you cannot ignore whitespace.

Comment: acheong87, thanks, that's what I want, but the opposite, I don't want the "," ones, only the "

Comment: @Amien - That's what I already did.  The ``[^,]`` means **non**-comma.  The ``(?<!,)`` and ``(?!,)`` are **negative** lookbehind and lookahead assertions.

Comment: Thank you very much! the [^,]"[^,] works great, just it selects the chars on either side of the ", want it to just select the "

Comment: Ah, I'm afraid you may be out of luck.  For that you need the lookahead/lookbehind assertions, and Notepad++ apparently doesn't support these.  However, if you're doing a find-and-replace, perhaps you can capture the characters on each side, e.g. ``([^,])"([^,])``, and bring them back in your replacement using backreferences, e.g. ``\1blah\2``.